# Filter the period in Char[]

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

The valid sudoku problem on Leetcode is solved, however, there is still a little question regarding the '.', which I fail to filter until I try another way.

Check out the comment parts regarding (1) & (2), (1) = the correct way to filter period by using continue; if '.' is found. (2) = is the wrong way which I used before, it will only allow digits to get passed for the following if statements.

Assume 1~9 digits and '.' will be the only inputs.

I just need someone to help me analyze the difference between these 2 ways, so I can learn from the mistakes.

Thank you for the help!

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean isValidSudoku(char[][] board) {
        if (board.length > 9 || board[0].length > 9 || board == null) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean[] brain;
        for (int x = 0; x < board.length; x++) {
            // Reset brain
            brain = new boolean[9];
            for (int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++) {

                // ------- (1) Begin -------
                if (board[x][y] == '.') {
                    continue;
                }
                if (brain[board[x][y] - '1']) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    brain[board[x][y] - '1'] = true;
                }
                // ------- (1) End -------

                // statments (1) above is the correct one, I used to use code below:
                /*
                // ------- (2) Begin -------
                if (board[x][y] != '.') {
                    if (brain[board[x][y] - '1']) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        brain[board[x][y] - '1'] = true;
                    }
                }
                // ------- (2) Begin -------
                */
                // which failed for not filter out '.' properly
                // so I changed to filter '.' out by using continue;
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < board.length; x++) {
            // Reset brain
            brain = new boolean[9];
            for (int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++) {
                if (board[y][x] == '.') {
                    continue;
                }
                if (brain[board[y][x] - '1']) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    brain[board[y][x] - '1'] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int block = 0; block < 9; block++) {
            // Reset brain
            brain = new boolean[9];
            for (int r = block / 3 * 3; r < block / 3 * 3 + 3; r++) {
                for (int c = block % 3 * 3; c < block % 3 * 3 + 3; c++) {
                    if (board[r][c] == '.') {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (brain[board[r][c] - '1']) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        brain[board[r][c] - '1'] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `for (int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++) {` be `for (int y = 0; y < board[x].length; y++) {`?

Comment: @pzaenger that's a good way to catch the correct dimension structure. But in this particular case, it is sure that matrix is perfect 9 * 9, so I don't think it is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two methods you use to skip dots on your Sudoku board are equivalent under the assumption that the digits 1 thru 9 and the dot are your only input.

I have tried to verify this with two different Sudoku boards, and both methods returned the same result. As I believe the two methods to do the same I think you will be hard pressed to find a board that shows differing results for each method.